# Xamarin Forms Basic BindingContext to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do some basic data binding from my XAML view to my view model in my Xamarin Forms (4.2) app. I navigate to the `PhotoUploadPage` from a different page.

**PhotoUploadPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="AgentConnectMobile.Views.PhotoUploadPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="Upload Photo"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentPage.Content>
            <!--Upload.Id below isn't showing -->
            <Label Text="{Binding Upload.Id}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

**PhotoUploadPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PhotoUploadPage : ContentPage
{
    PhotoUploadViewModel viewModel;

    public PhotoUploadPage(PhotoUploadViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        BindingContext = this.viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**PhotoUploadViewModel.cs**

```
public class PhotoUploadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Upload Upload { get; set; }

    public PhotoUploadViewModel(Upload upload = null)
    {
        Upload = upload;
    }
}
```

**Upload.cs**

```
public class Upload
{
    public string Id;
}
```

**Navigate to PhotoUploadPage**

```
var upload = new Upload
{
    Id = "abc123",
};

await Navigation.PushAsync(new PhotoUploadPage(new PhotoUploadViewModel(upload)));
```

I put breakpoints in `PhotoUploadPage.xaml.cs` and the BindingContext is getting set and I can see `Upload` on it with my Id value, but the value never appears in the Label text. I have also switched the order of `InitializeComponent()` and setting the BindingContext but that didn't solve anything either.

What am I doing wrong? I believe I'm doing this other places and it is working just fine...

Comment: is `Id` a public property on Upload?

Comment: Yes. `Id` is a `public string`

Comment: but is it a **property**?  (ie, it has a `get`)  You can only bind to properties, not to fields.

Comment: Thank you! That was it.